# Windows/clang linker undefined symbol mainCRTStartup

Tags: windows, compilation, linker, clang

I compile using Clang, and need to bundle different .obj files into one .lib. This one .lib is then compiled into executable. Problem is that, however it works on Unix(ld.lld -r files... -o file.lib), i can't use -r for lld-link, and using /lib option results in error:

```
lld-link: error: <root>: undefined symbol: mainCRTStartup
```

I tried same process, but with unix. Here, we have ELF object files and can perform -relocatable(-r) to merge ELF objects into one. On windows, there's no -relocatable option for COFF, afaik. And /LIB actually produces a bundle, not a COFF Object. If i don't use /LIB for my main-containing COFF file, executable compiles.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can merge COFF or MACH-O object files in one, but i solved my issue with mainCRTStartup.

My Final.lib file is a mix of literally everything from my code, it's assembled from individual .obj files from all my project.

I compile it using ld(insert correct driver) -r(/lib) file1.obj file2.obj... -o(/out:)Final.lib

And now most valuable moment! Now this .lib we must compile using Clang

```
clang++ -fuse-ld=lld Final.lib -o App.a(exe)
```

This is only thing, that actually resolves my problem. I have no idea, why Using LLD as LD fixes everything, but just live with it, ok?

Goodluck, friends!